# solving simultaneous linear congruences and simplifying the mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I wanted to solve the following:

$x\equiv2 (\text{mod 3})$

$x\equiv5 (\text{mod 6})$

$x\equiv7 (\text{mod 8})$

I rewrote the first congruence as $x=2+3a$ and in (mod 6), this can be written $2+3a\equiv5(\text{mod 6})$, which has solution $a\equiv1 (\text{mod 6})$, which implies $a=1+6k$.

Substituting this in for our first expression for $x$ gives $x=5+18k$ which can be written as $x\equiv5 (\text{mod 18})$.

I repeated this process with new expression for $x$ and the expression mod 8 and found that $x\equiv23 (\text{mod 144})$, however apparently the answer is $x\equiv23 (\text{mod 24})$. I am confused about how they simplified the mod?

Comment: if $x\equiv2\pmod3$ and $x\equiv7\pmod8$ then $x\equiv5\pmod6$ automatically

Comment: Things are a bit complicated because your moduli are not relatively prime.  In such a situation, some of your congruences are either redundant (as in your case) or contradictory (not a problem here).  Best to rephrase your congruences in terms of the relatively prime $3$ and $8$, though you must check that then your other congruence is forced.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner could you please remind me why that is the case?

Comment: "this can be written 2+3a≡5(mod 6), which has solution a≡1(mod 6),"  No.  $3a\equiv 3\pmod 6$ which has *three* solutions.  $a\equiv 1$ and $a\equiv 3$ and $a\equiv 5$.  This is probably compounded when you repeated.

Comment: "ould you please remind me why that is the case?"  Chinese Remainder theorem.  If $x \equiv a \pmod 3$ and $x \equiv b \pmod 8$ there will be a unique solution  $x=K \pmod {24}$.  This will "force"  $x \equiv c \pmod 6$ to agree with $x \equiv K \pmod 6$.... specifically. If $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv 7\pmod 8$ then $x\equiv 23\pmod{24}$.  And so $x = 23 + 24k$.  So $x \equiv 23 + 24k\equiv 23\equiv 5 \pmod 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese remainder thereom says we can solve a system uniquely for the product of the moduli if the moduli are relatively prime.  In this case the are *not* relatively prime. But, if the equations are consistent, we can solve them uniquely for the least common multiple of the moduli... *if the equations are consistent*.

We can solve this for $\pmod {\operatorname{lcm}(3*6*8)= 24}$. but breaking $24$ into relatively prime components $3*8$.

The thing to keep in mind is that if $a\equiv k \pmod {mn}$ then $a\equiv k \pmod n$ (because $mn|a-k$ so $n|a-k).

So $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

And $x \equiv 5\pmod 6$ so $x\equiv 5\equiv 2\pmod 3$.  (Two things to note: 1) this is why the equations must be consistent.  if we had $x \equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $x \equiv 4\pmod 6$ we'd have $x \equiv 4\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and that would not be consistent. $x\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ *and* $x\equiv 4 \pmod 6$ is not possible.  2) We also have $x\equiv 5\equiv 1\pmod 2$.  But we don't need that.)

So $x \equiv 2\pmod 3$.

And $x \equiv 7\pmod 8$.

so we can solve those to and get a unique solution $x \equiv 23\pmod {24}$.

.... oh, I get what they were getting at....

> Tangential aside:
>
> $x \equiv 2\equiv -1\pmod 3$ and $x \equiv 5\equiv -1 \pmod 6$ and $x\equiv 7\equiv -1 \pmod 8$
>
> So we have $x \equiv -1 \pmod{ 3,6,8}$.
>
> And if $x\equiv k \pmod m$ and $x\equiv k \pmod n$ and we want to know *a* (not necessarily unique solution) to $x \equiv ???? \pmod {W}$ then $x\equiv k\pmod W$ is always *one* solution. (Although and $k + am + bn\pmod{W}$ will *also* be a solution.
>
> So $x \equiv -1\pmod 24$ will be a solution.  And as $\gcd(3,8)=1$ that solution will be unique $\mod 24$.

=====

Your error was in solving

$2+3a = x\equiv 5\pmod 6$  so $2+3a \equiv 5\pmod 6$ so $3a \equiv 3\pmod 6$ does *NOT* mean $a \equiv 1 \pmod 6$.  Modular arithmetic does *not* hold for divisiong if the moduli are *not* relatively prime.

$3*1 \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ but $3*3=9\equiv 3 \pmod 6$ and $3*5\equiv 15 \equiv 3\pmod 6$.  so $a \equiv 1,3,5 \pmod 6$.

Note if $ma \equiv mb \equiv W$ then $W|ma-mb=m(a-b)$ but that does *not* mean $W|a-b$.  It's possible that $W$ and $m$ have  a factor in common.

But if $\gcd(m,W)=1$ then $W$ and $m$ *don't* have a factor in common and you can divide  But *not* if they *do* have a factor in common.

So instead of getting $x = 5+18k$ we should have gotten $x = 5,11,17 + 18k$.  Three possibible results, not just one.

ANd this way of doing it would eventually have ended with $x \equiv  23,47,71,95,119,143 \pmod{144}$.

Answer (score 0):

As [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) explained in a comment, when moduli are not relatively prime, simultaneous congruences could be redundant or contradictory.  In your case, $\color{blue}3$ and $\color{blue}8$ are relatively prime, but $6$ is not, and as long as $x\equiv2\pmod3$ and $x\equiv7\pmod8$, then $x\equiv-1\pmod3$ and $x\equiv-1\pmod2$, so $x\equiv-1\pmod6$, and $x\equiv5\pmod6$ is redundant.  That is how the answer became modulo $\color{blue}3\times\color{blue}8=24$.